# Properties file changes are not reflecting unless restarting Glassfish server

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I am using JSF2.0 and Glassfish v3.

I have a ValidatorMessage.properties file under WEB-INF>Classes folder of my project.

When I make any changes to messages in this file, through my project, its changes are not reflected.

I access this messages through  `<f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="ValidationMessages"/>`

Are there any configurations to be made in Glassfish or my project side?

P.S.-> the same functionality works under Jetty 7.0.0pre3

Please comment if question is not clear..

Comment: how do you reload your `ResourceBundle`?

Comment: @org.life.java- I clear the cacheList of the ResouceBundle, assuming loadbundle to reload when found null.
As the way described here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047891/how-to-reload-resourcebundles-that-are-used-by-jsf

Comment: Issues with properties being changed requiring a server restart comes down to reload of resource bundle as mentioned in comments above I had similar issue was solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660117/how-to-update-the-jsf2-0-primefaces-tooltips-dynamically-without-server-restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to restart the server when you make change in a properties file.
I often do changes in my files for internationalization and i don't need to restart.

I don't know what IDE do you use, but i use eclipse and there i have an option when i double click on Glassfish application server to automatically publish when changes are detected(See image below). I think that is what you are looking for.

[image]

Also there is a podcast from oracle that mentions it(**time 2.04**)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppGqtOeHm-g&feature=related